# Trying to change a href string using Jasvascript and Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, string, replace, href, tampermonkey

I'm trying to get the YouTube logo link on the site to link to my subscriptions by using Tampermonkey.

This is what I'm trying to change

```
<a id="logo-container" href="/" title="YouTube home" class=" "><img id="logo" src="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt="YouTube home"><span class="content-region">NL</span></a>
```

I'm trying to change the

> href="/"

to

> href="/feed/subscriptions"

This is the code I am using now and I have no idea why it doesn't work

```
var newURL = "/feed/subscriptions";
onload=function() {
    var dt = document.getElementById("logo-container");
    document.body.innerHTML = dt.getAttributeNode("href").value.replace("/",newURL);
}
```

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML =` You're overwriting the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.body.innerHTML = dt.getAttributeNode("href").value.replace("/",newURL);
```

You're setting the HTML of the `<body>` tag to a string. What did you expect this to do?

If all you're trying to do is modify the `href` attribute on the `<a>` tag, try instead doing something more like:

```
document.getElementById('logo-container').href = "/feed/subscriptions";
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a complete noob when it comes to JavaScript. It worked perfectly